# Using an HTML form to generate a string?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to make a page that will take a username, password, and email to create a user on my SubSonic page. I've got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    var server = "http://*****.*****.org:4040/rest/createUser.view?";
    var params = "&commentRole=true&u=*****&p=*****&v=1.12.0&c=myapp"; 
    var tosend = server.concat(form,params);
    document.write(tosend);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
   Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=myFunction()>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I enter text into the fields I get an output like this:

```
http://*****.*****.org:4040/rest/createUser.view?[object HTMLFormElement]&commentRole=true&u=*****&p=*****&v=1.12.0&c=myapp
```

I've been searching, trying to figure out how to get that [object HTMLFormElement] to generate into a string. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: document.getElementById("myForm") will always give a object.If you want to use the value, you can get it by document.getElementById("someDomElement").value;

Comment: Why do you involve javascript at all?

Comment: Is it not the way I should? I'm still brand new to all of this, trying new things out and finding out that I'm wrong all the time, hah.

Comment: .value is giving me "undefined&comment" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something simple like this in your script tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var server = "http://*****.*****.org:4040/rest/createUser.view?";
        var params = "&commentRole=true&u=*****&p=*****&v=1.12.0&c=myapp"; 

        var name = document.getElementsByName("name").value;    
        var password = document.getElementsByName("password").value;
        var email = document.getElementsByName("email").value;

        /*
            to access tag values by name
            name=document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
            password=document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
            email=document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;

            looping this will do
        */  

        var tosend = server + "" + "name=" + name + "&password=" + password + "&email=" + email + "" + params;
        document.write(tosend);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="name"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
   Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=myFunction()>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

actually any dynamic ways of getting form values will do, one example is looping form values and storing it on variables.